# Sequel not working with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I'm trying to migrate my Rails apps to PostGreSql in order to work in the same environnement as on heroku...

I installed postgres, pg, and postgres-pr fine on my mac but I can't get Taps to pull my databases off from Heroku to my postgresql server.

My Rails Apps connect seamlessly to the database.

When I run into the irb this is what I get:

```
>> require "rubygems"
=> false
>> require "sequel"
=> true
>> DB = Sequel.postgres
NameError: uninitialized constant Sequel::Postgres::PGError
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:89
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `k_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `check_requiring_thread'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:63:in `connect'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:282:in `adapter_method'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:289:in `postgres'
    from (irb):3
>>
```

I don't understand what's going wrong.

Does anybody have an idea?

---

This is what I get Jeremy

```
BigMac:~ jp$ ruby -rubygems -rpg -e "p PGError"
ruby: no such file to load -- pg (LoadError)
BigMac:~ jp$ ruby -rubygems -rpostgres -e "p PGError"
ruby: no such file to load -- postgres (LoadError)
```

I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "Check for a pg.rb or postgres.rb somewhere in your path"

Should I scan all the directories in my $PATH and look for an unwanted pg.rb or postgres.rb file?

---

That's weird because I did install pg and postgre

Here is what I just ran

```
BigMac:/ jp$ sudo gem install pg
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.10.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.10.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.10.0...
BigMac:/ jp$ ruby -rubygems -rpg -e "p PGError"
ruby: no such file to load -- pg (LoadError)
BigMac:/ jp$
```

Comment: Please run `gem search pg postgres` at the command-line and edit your original question, adding the output. If you get no output then it sounds like you need to run `gem install pg`.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the exact same problem trying to run heroku db:pull to my local postgresql database using the pg gem. Randomly ended up fixing the problem by removing the following gems:

```
activerecord-jdbc-adapter 
activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter
```

Tried it again after removing those gems and managed to pull from heroku successfully. Try checking your gem file for any gems that relate to postgres other than your pg gem and remove it. All the best

Comment: Hey 2potatocakes, I did a gem update heroku and everything worked fine after that. I'll keep your answer if it starts happening again!

Comment: This worked for me too, unbelievable!  Nice job @2potatocakes

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, whatever postgres or pg file you are requiring does not define the PGError class.  Check for a pg.rb or postgres.rb somewhere in your path.

What happens when you ruby the following:

```
ruby -rubygems -rpg -e "p PGError"
ruby -rubygems -rpostgres -e "p PGError"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the [postgres adapter](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb) source code, you can see it attempts to load the `pg` Ruby gem followed by the `postgres` gem (prioritized in that order). According to your output of `ruby -rubygems -rpg -e "p PGError"` You don't have the `pg` gem, nor do you have the `postgres` gem installed on your system.

Make sure you run `gem install pg` and try that line again, if that doesn't work it becomes a Rubygems issue and not a Sequel issue. If you're able to load `pg` then `PGError` will be defined.